# How do you detect if a message says 'Thank you'?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I have various messages, and I want to know if the essence of the message is saying 'Thank you'. This disregards messages where it says 'Thank you' and includes a question.

Comment: search for the substring "Thank you" ??

Comment: All you need is a small research team and a couple of years of intense study.

Comment: You could use a [bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) and train it with a manually tagged data set :-)

Comment: This is a non trivial question that you can't simply call an inbuilt funtion to solve. If all you need is specifically the presence of the string 'thank you' then search for it as @OMGtechy suggested.

If not you need labelled training data on expressions that imply 'thank you' then you can train a classifier and subsequently classifiy new instances

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used the word "essence," this is an extremely difficult question to answer exhaustively and completely.

Let's step back a bit here: a lot of work has been done on a related problem called sentiment analysis. This is, in some respect, an interesting subset of that problem because it's defined a lot better.

> Naysayer: Defined better!? Why, sentiment analysis is very clearly defined. It's a map from text to a review score of some kind. This is some kind of wishy-washy...

The problem with that naysayer's critique is that the notion of sentiment given there really isn't well-defined. What is the meaning of a "star rating?" How can that be related to language? It's not quite clear, and existing approaches have struggled with this in some respects.

"Expressing thanks" is, in fact, much clearer than "expressing a sentiment." We can think of thanks as a particular type of sentiment, and in fact, a very specific one--one that, I suspect, human annotators can reliably mark up. If humans can mark up a phenomenon reliably, that's what computational and corpus linguists consider sufficient criteria for something being "real."

There's two approaches you can take here. One will be faster; one will be more revealing.

The first is to think of all strings related to thankfulness you can come up with, and search for those. This is, in other words, the extended version of @OMGtechy's snarky comment up there. There's obviously "thank you", but also "thanks", "I (really) appreciate(d)", "your kindness", "was so kind", "am grateful". You could probably get pretty good coverage of your data quickly.

The second is a bit more difficult, but it has the advantage of challenging your intuitions. Get a list of messages, and mark whether they are "thankful" or not. In each message, mark up the part that showed you the person was grateful. You could take your results from this part and use them to bolster the first part.

I suspect, with gratitude, the patterns are quite regular. When expressing gratitude, we often enter a particular register of language use, and there's--according to my "first part" intuitions--a rather limited set of words we use. No fancy NLP required--just exhaustive pattern matching there. If that's the case, there's some interesting linguistics at play here.